# Terraform :error creating role rds_pgaudit: pq: role "rds_pgaudit" already exists

Tags: postgresql, terraform, amazon-rds

I am trying trying the restore the RDS cluster with latest snapshot. Where the snapshot already  has the role.

I am using

> provider "postgresql"

```
resource "postgresql_role" "rds_pgaudit_role" {
  name                  = var.rds_pgaudit_role
  skip_reassign_owned   = false
  skip_drop_role        = true
  depends_on            = [ aws_rds_cluster_instance.db_cluster_instance[0] ]
}
```

After "terraform apply". RDS is getting restored but I am getting an error as below

```
Error: error creating role rds_pgaudit: pq: role "rds_pgaudit" already exists

  on users.tf line 2, in resource "postgresql_role" "rds_pgaudit_role":
   2: resource "postgresql_role" "rds_pgaudit_role" {
```

Is there any workaround or how to resolve for this?